# Inserting/appending into an unordered_map<int, unordered_map<string, object>>

Tags: c++, insert, unordered-map

I just have a quick question for you.

I'm currently working on a Homework Assignment that I started from scratch. Our goal is to create a program that takes a bunch of CSV files and merge them into one, using the Unique ID Number as the Key.

My **main question** here is a simple one (Yet, I haven't been able to figure out the correct syntax to do so).

How do I go about inserting into this:

```
unordered_map<int, unordered_map<string, object>>
```

I can figure out how to get the Key Value (ID # which is an Int) into the Unordered map, but after that, I'm completely lost. (Meaning, I have an unordered_map just filled with Key Values, but nothing connecting them to any other data.)

I've attempted a couple of different methods, but none of them have prevailed.

If you'd like to see the code to get a better grasp of what I'm asking, feel free to ask! (I'm using Visual Studios 2013 by the way, as well as using namespace std)

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: `the_outer_map[the_int_key] = the_inner_map;`

Comment: `the_outer_map[the_int_key][the_string_key] = the_object;` if you start with objects... separately, you could create an `unordered_map<pair<int, string>, object>` instead but you'd have to write your own hash function (plenty of examples on stackoverflow using `boost::hash_combine` or a "clone").

Comment: @TonyD: Is the_outer_map a name? I did not realize I can name my inner and outer maps. I have the outer map named, but not the inner. How do I do that? Thanks for the response! EDIT: Additionally, I'm using a pair<string, int> regarding the category and score a student gets. Since the string in the pair is linked with the int, how do I go about using the String of the pair as the String_Key?      Thanks again! 

juanchopanza, I appreciate your time! Thank you.

Comment: @TonyD: I actually just figured it out! I used 

outermap[int_key][pair.first] = the_object

Woohoo! I've been wondering about that this whole weekend. I appreciate it again, both of you!

Comment: I'm just back online - congrats on sorting it out....  Cheers.